# Button in table column doesn't wait for the onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I've got a table where last column should work as a "delete item" button. Table looks something like this:

```
const columns = ({ onClick }) => [
  {
    key: 'type',
    onRender: (item) => (
      <p className="ms-font-m mb-0">
        {item.type}
      </p>
    ),
  },
  {
    key: 'remove',
    onRender: (item) => (
      <PrimaryButton onClick={onClick(item.type)}>
        <FormattedMessage {...messages.removeLight}/>
      </PrimaryButton>
    ),

  },
]

const Table = ({ data, onClick, intl}) => (
  <Table
    items={data}
    compact
    columns={columns({ onClick })}
  />
);
```

, where the onClick event calls function that rewrites current state and sets the new one, like this:

```
handleRemove = (type) => {
    const { form } = this.state

    var itemsNew = form.items.filter(e => e.type !== type),

    this.setState({
      form: itemsNew,
    });
  }
```

Problem is, that when the table is rendered the `handleRemove` function is called immediately and doesn't wait for the click event. However, if i remove the `item.type` parameter and call `handleRemove` as an empty function with some `console.log(...)` line only, it works just fine.

I am very new to JS and really don't get what am i missing here.

Comment: You are invoking `onClick` directly on render. Give the `onClick` prop a function instead. `onClick={() => onClick(item.type)}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change this line
`<PrimaryButton onClick={onClick(item.type)}>`
to `<PrimaryButton onClick={() => onClick(item.type)}>`

Another solution is to change function 'shape' from this `handleRemove = (type) => {...}` to this `handleRemove = (type) => () => {...}`

Comment: wow, really missed that. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinDršata Glad to help. Also don't forget to mark an answer as correct if it helps you to solve your problem.